# Wordcloud tags not appearing in a given fontSize - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I will be working on wordcloud using highcharts. This is my array containing name and weight for each tag.

```
var wordArray = [{
  name: 'America',
  weight: 1
}, {
  name: 'Australia',
  weight: 2
}, {
  name: 'North AMerica',
  weight: 3
}, {
  name: 'India',
  weight: 4
}, {
  name: 'SOUTH TEXAS',
  weight: 5
}];
```

And here i will be assigning font size to each tag.

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function(relativeWeight) {
  var maxFontSize = 10;
  // Will return a fontSize based on maxFontSize.
  var rWeight = Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight);
  var size = rWeight < 1 ? 1 : rWeight;
  //based upon given maxFontSize the value become 10px, 8px, 6px, 4px, 2px to the corresponding tags 
  return size;
};
```

Herewith attached my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/eqtyotxm/2/). Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Is this correct http://jsfiddle.net/eqtyotxm/3/. By the way your existing code has no issue check https://imgur.com/a/LV5Dw

Comment: `deriveFontSize` is used to assign the fontsize to each tags. Please check with the image. https://imgur.com/sw1wfZv

Comment: adjust `weight` accordingly to get required size. You can try for decimal value to fine tune differences

Answer (score 1):

After the font sizes are computed word cloud sales the series group to fit it withing the plot area.

You can disable this by overwriting `getScale` function:

```
  var getScale = function getScale(targetWidth, targetHeight, field) {
    /*
    var height = Math.max(Math.abs(field.top), Math.abs(field.bottom)) * 2,
      width = Math.max(Math.abs(field.left), Math.abs(field.right)) * 2,
      scaleX = 1 / width * targetWidth,
      scaleY = 1 / height * targetHeight;
    return Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    */
    return 1;
  };
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/06dpcrss/

Architecture of the word cloud script doesn't allow to access some of the functions after the script finishes. They need to be copied too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamil Kulig